# Why can't Mysql be scalable as NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, nosql

I always read that MySQL is not as scalable as NoSQL databases. That is one of main disadvantage of relational databases. Why is it so? Why it can't be scalable as NoSQL databases. We can easily make it distributed by Sharding I think, then why is it so?

Either my thinking is wrong somewhere.

Comment: When you, say, break your mysql database into two shards and switch between them in the application logic, then congrats, you just broke transactions. You know can't run an ACID transaction that spans both shards. This is just an example. NoSQL databases solve this by not having ACID at all, even in single node mode. :)

Comment: Some RDBMSs _can_ shard and have all/most of functionality, though (MS SQL Server, I heard).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, what about DTC (distributed transaction)?

Comment: @Rahul: the microsoft software? what about it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Yes, not sure about other platform but if it's .NET framework then you can implement DTC. Read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684146(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Rahul: interesting. It's been a long time since I worked with .net. So haven't heard about this one. Thanks :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, that's alright and it was just a fyi ... your comment is perfect and make sense cause not every platform may have that facility. And so yes, as you said ... *you just broke transactions*

Comment: Is it really a limitation of relational databases? Or of the MySQL architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to implement transaction that would span over multiple parallel network nodes still meeting all [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) requirements. Not only it is required to support any nodes going up and down at any time, it is also required to support the fragmentation of the network, when it is split into multiple still working parts, and each part is no longer aware of that others are doing.

If this problem is somehow worked around or is not important for the particular solution, if the database only needs to be eventually consistent, it should be no reasons other than true or perceived lack of good implementations for the clustering.

Something that was written as a distributed database from beginning may be easier to work with.